# upgrade from windows 7 to windows 10 caused disk failure

Tags: windows, upgrade, windows-10

last week I started upgrading a computer (HP Pro 3120 bought since 2011 I think) at one of my clients's office, I upgraded from windows 7 to windows 10.

To do the upgrade I used first the windows tool available at the windows website in order to make an install dvd (windows 10 pro x86) that I used to upgrade. The machine is running windows 7 pro 32bit.

The upgrade itself didn't report any error during the install.

when the installation completed there was a problem with the windows 
explorer not working correctly it crashed some times.

The task manager showed a lot of usage of the hard drive.

And in the event log there was an error about an access to a database that was unable to be accessed.

So I left the computer about an hour I was thinking that the upgrade was doing some background tasks.

When I came back the hard drive usage was normal. so to verify that the upgrade was ok I rebooted the computer and here was the problem.

at the first reboot the windows boot screen showed and it was not normal the animation in it was too slow then it crashed and rebooted automatically

at the second reboot it showed an alert that the hard drive was in a critical situation that I must backup my data

I tryed to continue the boot but windows failed to open just the windows boot screen showed up and then it crash

at the third boot the bios didn't even detect the hard drive. Houston we have a problem haha

I had to buy a new Hard drive reinstall windows 7 on it and restore the backed up files.

Now I want to understand why the hard drive failed during the upgrade process was it not supported by windwos 10 ? the Hard drive is a SATA 3.0 with 320GB

Comment: This question is more for SuperUser, but for an answer, you asked a *lot* of IO when you did the upgrade, thus if the drive was near dead, you killed it. Not for nothing if you want to recover, everyone would told you to remove the HDD and to recover offline, to prevent IO to kill the drive

Comment: you mean what by recover offline ?

Comment: I mean to remove the hdd from that system and connect it to another computer that the windows is not running on it.

Comment: you mean insert it in another computer as a slave Hard drive ? ok I'll try that but my main problem isn't recovering the files I already done that and the comuter is operational. I have two other computer that are the same as this one and I'm confused can I continue my upgrade process or the HDD is not compatible or just leave as it is with windows 7

Comment: This question is more for SuperUser, but **for an answer, you asked a lot of IO when you did the upgrade, thus if the drive was near dead, you killed it.**  Not a compatibility problem.

Comment: ok then I'll look for a tool to see Hard drive's life status thank you you can answer the question to not let it unanswered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked a lot of IO when you did the upgrade, thus if the drive was near dead, you killed it. Not a compatibility problem.

A side note; Not for nothing if you want to recover, everyone would told you to remove the HDD and to recover offline, to prevent IO to kill the drive